# How can I pass an HTML file content from PHP to CGI (Perl) Script

Tags: php, html, scripting, cgi, data-transfer

The content of the an HTML file generated by a PHP is stored in a string variable called

```
$output
```

I am trying to send the contents in $output to a CGI script.

I have tried the following CURL in PHP...

```
$output = "long string, with strange non HTML characters..."
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/script.cgi');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output);
curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

...but I only get a small part of the $output content.

Do you have any recommendations on how to pass the content of $output from PHP to the CGI/Perl script?

Thanks!

Comment: Be VERY careful, generating dynamic code can easily lead to being exploited.  I've never been in a situation where it was required and I'm a firm believer that when you are doing this, you are most likely designing your solution wrong.

Comment: I will definitely need to redesign the whole system... this is a quick fix to have a prototype running.
Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it suits you but you can do that:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("output" => $output));
```

This will sent your data as value of the POST field named 'output'

You may also use socket functions to open connection to server and send your own fully custom http request.

Comment: Works like a perfectly!
Thanks!